# ASP.Net Core: passing configuration values to JavaScript client code

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, configuration

I want to pass configuration values from `appsettings.json` in ASP.Net Core / 5.0 to a client-side plain JavaScript code; the parameters will not be changed after setup. What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

**1 - expose a controller action to fetch configuration and call the backend from JS.**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public ValuesController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    [HttpGet("config")]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        var data = new
        {
            SomeValue = _config["SomeValue"]
        };
        return Ok(data);
    }
}

fetch('api/values/config').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
```

**2 - write the vales directly to the HTML page.**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public HomeController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new HomeIndexModel
        {
            SomeValue = _config["SomeValue"]
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model MyApp.Controllers.HomeIndexModel;

<script type="text/javascript">
    window['portalData'] = @Json.Serialize(Model);
</script>

<app-root></app-root>
```